# Is it possible to use multiple content databases for a site subscription in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We'd like to set up a site subscription but the 200gb limit content db is holding us back. Can we use multiple content databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A content database is associated with a Site Collection. You have full control on which Content DB the Site Collection will get created. I am not a site subscription expert, but I went through a couple of quick articles http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/12/30/multi-tenancy-in-sharepoint-2010-part-2.aspx, and it appears that you create site collections for that. Hence, my calculated guess is that it should be possible to have multiple content database.

Keep in mind that to create a Site Collection into a specific content DB, the other content DBs should be made offline from Central Admin. http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/creating-a-site-collection-in-a-new-content-database/